# Altering keyboard layout on plugging in or out

Tags: xorg, udev, xmodmap

I use an external keyboard with my laptop and a script to change
the keyboard layout depending on whether the keyboard is plugged
in.  This works fine, but I find it shouldn't be necessary to run
the script manually: it should run by itself whenever the external
keyboard is plugged in or out.  I've tried to set this up with a
udev rule, but for some reason it doesn't work.
My udev rule is:

```
KERNEL=="3-1.1", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", RUN+="/root/bin/udev.sh"
```

I have confirmed that this script runs once whenever I plug the
keyboard in or out.
The contents of the script are:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
su - toothrot -c "/usr/local/bin/loadkb.sh" &
```

And the contents of `/usr/local/bin/loadkb.sh` are:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:0 
export XAUTHORITY=/home/toothrot/.Xauthority
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus

killall xcape

if lsusb | grep HHKB
then {
    setxkbmap us,gr \
        -variant carpalx-plus-intl,daedalus \
        -option grp:win_space_toggle \
        -option lv3:rwin_switch \
        -option altwin:meta_alt \
        -option shift:breaks_caps \
        -option lv5:lsgt_switch_lock
    xmodmap ~/.xmodmap/hh 
    xcape -e 'Shift_L=F13;Shift_R=F14;Super_L=Prior;Hyper_L=Prior'
}
else {
    setxkbmap us,gr \
        -variant carpalx-plus-intl,daedalus \
        -option grp:win_space_toggle \
        -option lv3:ralt_switch \
        -option altwin:meta_alt \
        -option shift:breaks_caps -option lv5:lsgt_switch_lock
    xmodmap ~/.xmodmap/apple
    xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape;Shift_L=F14;Shift_R=F13;Alt_L=Escape;Alt_R=Escape'
}
fi
```

I have confirmed that running `/root/bin/udev.sh` as root works
for my toothrot X session.  Only when run by a udev rule, the
script doesn't work.  What am I missing?

Or is there a way to achieve the result I want without using a
udev rule, maybe from within X?

Comment: As an experiment, you might place `echo HHKB >/tmp/kbdlog` at the top of the `then` block, and `echo other >/tmp/kbdlog` at the top of the `else`, to ensure the correct path is taken

Comment: @Fox, I've confirmed that this writes the expected content to `/tmp/kbdlog`.

Comment: Could you send the `stdout` and `stderr` of each command to a similar log? That is, `command >/tmp/kbdlog 2>&1` for each command? See if any errors pop up there?

Comment: Udev-rules are run from the kernel and apparently execute in some kind of restricted environment. There are multiple questions on this site where doing something fancy or X related inside an udev-rule didn't work. I don't know how to solve this, if it's solvable at all. However, if the differences are simple enough, alternatively you can try to change the [scancode to keycode mapping](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes) on the input-layer with the hwdb integrated into udev.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/337411/how-to-permanently-assign-a-different-keyboard-layout-to-a-usb-keyboard may help: someone has managed to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this blog article](https://www.facility9.com/2019/07/09/remapping-keys-in-linux/) I got `xmodmap` to work with the following rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-usb-keyboards.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0000", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0000", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'DISPLAY=:0.0 XAUTHORITY=/home/toothrot/.Xauthority sh -c \"setxkbmap us,gr;xmodmap /home/toothrot/.xmodmap/hh\" &'"
```

Replace vendor and product id with the values of your device from `lsusb` and adjust the script to your liking, then don’t forget to  reload the udev rules with:

```
udevadm control --reload
```

I’d always leave the detection to udev, so this is the rule for when the keyboard is added. To act on removal add another rule line with:

```
ACTION=="remove"
```

Comment: Link to https://facility9.com/2019/07/remapping-keys-in-linux/: `404: Not Found` :(.

Comment: @pevik fixed it

Comment: I think it is worth calling out in this answer that the `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` environment variables are important. The linked article does a good job.