# Keyboard layout (xmodmap) on plugin depends on Desktop used? (e.g. KDE)

Tags: xorg, udev, xmodmap

I'm using a wireless keyboard with modified layout as per **~/.Xmodmap**. Using exactly this file name ensures that after disconnecting and reconnecting the keyboard, the mapping is okay. But not on a  Linux Mint-machine with MATE 20.04 desktop; it works on a Mint-based machine with KDE desktop 18.04).

On the KDE machine, I tried to figure out which service is invoked by udevd upon plugging in (tested using a simple USB wired keyboard). Via udevadm info I get to a .rules file candidate that has `RUN+{builtin}` call.
Hence I cannot trace how exactly ~./Xmodmap is loaded in KDE.

Finally I found a solution in [Altering keyboard layout on plugging in or out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354363/altering-keyboard-layout-on-plugging-in-or-out)
But that's not what I intended, 'cos I intended to lift the mechanism onto the KDE machine.

**Any suggestion of using a sort of *backtrace* via any tracing tool in order to find out which service invokes xmodmap after plugging in would be welcome!**